# How can I use tiles in an ArcGIS .tpk file with Google Maps?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, google-maps, tiles

ArcGIS can export a map as server tiles as a compressed folder with the extension .tpk, as described in the  [ArcGIS documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000457000000).

However, it is not clear how I can get Google maps to read these files.

I have previously used a ruby script to generate tiles, but ArcGIS can generate them more rapidly. However, my application currently expects to find a set of .png tiles for each zoom level, e.g. for zoom level 3:

```
[user@server map]$ ls *-3.png
0-0-3.png  1-2-3.png  2-4-3.png  3-6-3.png  5-0-3.png  6-2-3.png  7-4-3.png
0-1-3.png  1-3-3.png  2-5-3.png  3-7-3.png  5-1-3.png  6-3-3.png  7-5-3.png
0-2-3.png  1-4-3.png  2-6-3.png  4-0-3.png  5-2-3.png  6-4-3.png  7-6-3.png
0-3-3.png  1-5-3.png  2-7-3.png  4-1-3.png  5-3-3.png  6-5-3.png  7-7-3.png
0-4-3.png  1-6-3.png  3-0-3.png  4-2-3.png  5-4-3.png  6-6-3.png
0-5-3.png  1-7-3.png  3-1-3.png  4-3-3.png  5-5-3.png  6-7-3.png
0-6-3.png  2-0-3.png  3-2-3.png  4-4-3.png  5-6-3.png  7-0-3.png
0-7-3.png  2-1-3.png  3-3-3.png  4-5-3.png  5-7-3.png  7-1-3.png
1-0-3.png  2-2-3.png  3-4-3.png  4-6-3.png  6-0-3.png  7-2-3.png
1-1-3.png  2-3-3.png  3-5-3.png  4-7-3.png  6-1-3.png  7-3-3.png
```

but it is not clear to me what the analagous representation of these files is in a .tpk layer. An example of my output is [map_tiles.tpk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iiil0qttid95ii7/map_tiles.tpk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the .tpk file, use the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript Extension to the Google Maps API](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/index.html) as described under [Available map cache properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000414000000) in the ArcGIS documentation.

Comment: Is this (8 yr old) answer still applicable? The first link seems to have changed as it is now a Sales page. In my case I have a .tpk file made by someone else that I want to turn into a GMaps Image Overlay, but I do not have ArcGIS or any related software, so that second link does not seem applicable to me. Any updated advice will be useful, or perhaps I should just post a new question.

Comment: After some sleuthing I found this: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/gmaps/help/topics/apiref.htm

Which perhaps is the new location of your first link, but It has no mention of .tpk anywhere. And according to another question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216237/arcgis-javascript-extension-for-the-google-maps-api-serverapi-arcgisonline-com) on the ArcGIS JS Gmaps API, it is now deprecated. Is there a good current solution for turning my 400MB .tpk file into a Google Maps Overlay?