# ArcGIS JavaScript Extension for the Google Maps API, serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/gmaps/

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, google-maps-api

My code using as the following:

**Google Maps API in V3:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&v3&key=AIzaSyDYSz77yXE6n8okoIz4S16GbWvgPEyfUwk"> </script>
```

**ArcGIS JavaScript Extension in V1.4:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/gmaps/?v=1.4"></script>
```

**Then in my runtask(poly) function (which is adding polygon on the map):**

```
mapExtension = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.MapExtension(map);
esri.arcgis.gmaps.Config.proxyUrl = "proxy.ashx";
var qtask = new esri.arcgis.gmaps.QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/0");
```

**But, my web application prompts an error like below:**

> ?v=1.4:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: GLatLng is not defined_57 @
>   ?v=1.4:2_256.execute @ ?v=1.4:2runtask @
>   Default.aspx?facilityname=Airgas+National+Welders+-+10+&street=1221+New+Savannah+Road+&city=Augusta…:635mapplume
>   @
>   Default.aspx?facilityname=Airgas+National+Welders+-+10+&street=1221+New+Savannah+Road+&city=Augusta…:599initialize
>   @
>   Default.aspx?facilityname=Airgas+National+Welders+-+10+&street=1221+New+Savannah+Road+&city=Augusta…:452onload
>   @
>   Default.aspx?facilityname=Airgas+National+Welders+-+10+&street=1221+New+Savannah+Road+&city=Augusta…:991

I checked `http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/gmaps/?v=1.4`, it has GLatLng class which is under Google Maps API V2, but I am using V3 now, do you have new version working with V3 (google.maps.LatLng) ? I cannot find any versions applied to V3, but I want to keep using the same code, like `esri.arcgis.gmaps.MapExtension` function.

Answer (score 1):

the ArcGIS JavaScript Extension for Google Maps was deprecated prior to the release of Google Maps v3.

check out this alternative project:
http://dev.huement.com/gmaps/arcgislink/docs/examples.html

Comment: Hi, John, <script src="/path/to/argislink_compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is not working for me. Do you know where can I get online?

Comment: I fixed the above problem. But I have another problem like how to generate polygons within a defined circle? what I mean is showing polygons highlight lines on the map. 
Besides, how to report census information from above polygons?
Thanks!    @John Gravois

Comment: Is there a new alternative project? Or at least a new link? That one is broken

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/archive/arcgislink